# Keyboard for developers

Tags: keyboard

Recently I installed SL4A application with Python interpreter. Everything is cool, but a standard keyboard, installed on my system (HTC Sense) doesn't have some necessary characters, like **[** and **]**, and some other. So it is impossible to write many things, and I have to use copy/paste from other text files.

Anyone knows about any keyboard with specific characters?

Comment: The default Android keyboard has those symbols, not sure if it's missing others you need however.

Comment: @matthew-read, you're right. I tried another flashware and found there needed characters! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [touchqode](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.touchqode.editor&feature=search_result).  It comes with a virtual keyboard specifically for programming.

Comment: It works, thanks! Only cons is that there are no other languages to switch

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [Hacker's keyboard application](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard)?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [graffiti](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.access_company.graffiti) handwriting app. There is a (surprisingly short) learning curve if you have not used a Palm PDA but it uses less screen estate than a keyboard, has "all" characters and, at least for me, allows faster typing.